# Injecting Dependency from BusinessLogic layer to facade to DataAccessLayer

Tags: c#, class

My WCF application receive RequestContext from UI, and I have three layer before fetching data from DB. Namely, BusinessLogicLayer, FacadeLayer, and DataAccessLayer. I have differnt classes in each layer to work on with that RequestContext object. I am passing RequestContext object to each layer's classes thru its constructor something like `new Facade(RequestContext rqstContext)`

Since I am having concrete class to receive the object, Is it best practice to have something like `new Facade(IRequestContext rqstContext)`, in which my RequestContext will implement IRequestContext/Or any abstract class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not get confused between OO(Object Orientation) and SO(Service Orientation). From your explanation the Request context class seems to be a DTO(Data transfer object). If your entity is purely used to transfer data, then there is no need to re-factor and Interface out of it.

Comment: Except the lower layers now take a dependence on an upper layer being web-related (specifically HTTP related.  e.g. HttpContext and RouteData?  What's that go to do with a Data Layer?

Comment: Did you read his comment properly?He says that he calls his custom made entity as RequestContext. He doesnt say that he uses System.Web.Routing.RequestContext

Comment: Based on the RequestContext from System.Web--which really only has HttpContext and RouteData.  He's trying to abstract away System.Web by creating his own interface; but what is *in* the original class still remains Web-specific.

Answer (score 1):

You're coupling your BusinessLogicLayer, FacadeLayer and DataAccessLayer to the fact that the front end is a Web app?  That defeats the purpose of layering.  The best practice is the abstract the fact that your front end is web and pass in only the parts of the RequestContext properties that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not getting you. Sorry

Comment: Let's say that you added a front end that was WPF, you'd no longer have anything that resembled RequestContext.  The fact that your other layers depend on a RequestContext (even if abstracted by an interface) means they depend on a WCF front end.  They're no longer layers because they have a dependency on something above them.

Comment: What parts of RequestContext are you using in each layer?

Comment: RequestContext is just an enitity with attributes so that i read the values and create an entry in DB

Comment: Using System.Web.Routing.RequestContext in any layer other than a web front-end layer means that layer takes a dependency on something web-based.  If you changed your front-end to something other than web it would no longer have any of the RequestContext information and render the lower layers useless.  you *could* createa a DTO to contain the information that you require from RequestContext and pass that DTO into the lower layers; but you're still liking taking a dependence on something web-related in those lower layers--which defeats the purpose of layers.

Comment: Request context is an entity defined by him